# Are there any distributed systems that completely use UDP instead of TCP?

Tags: networking, udp, system, distributed

I am trying to find some user cases of distributed systems (especially computing systems such as MLSys or graph computing systems), which completely rely on UDP as the communication primitve. But it seems everyone is using TCP. So I am curious whether there are some purely UDP-based distributed system (Of course, the application level should be more complex to track packet loss and retransmission, etc).

Comment: DNS, for a start, and DHCP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I am trying to find some *computing* system